# On Pepper Potts and Tony Stark's relationship

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, spider-man-homecoming

**Spoilers for "Captain America: Civil War" and "Spider-Man: Homecoming".**

In the first part of "Captain America: Civil War", Tony Stark tells Steve Rogers that

> Pepper Potts left him (I assumed that the real reason was that Gwyneth Paltrow was sick of the MCU).

Later in the film, he meets

> Peter Parker's Aunt May and starts openly flirting with her.

In the beginning of "Spider-Man: Homecoming", he constantly comments to Peter about how attractive he finds Aunt May, and I got the impression that they were planning on going somewhere with the May/Tony story, especially since he explicitly said that he saw himself as a father figure to Peter.

Then the May/Tony thread is dropped, and in the final scene of the movie

> Pepper Potts suddenly pops out of nowhere, and Tony indirectly proposes to her by asking Happy to give her the ring he has been carrying since 2008.

Did I miss something?

---

Some of the commenters pointed out that Tony flirting with May is just Tony being Tony. Taken on its own, maybe, but there's also the fact that:

> Tony mentions during one of the phone calls that he is trying to be a good father figure to Peter. Something along the line of "I'm trying to give you positive feedback, my father never gave me any..." or something similar (I can't find the exact quote)

Comment: [well, that's just what we call pillow talk, baby](https://media.giphy.com/media/yNVDyQN6GXUwo/giphy.gif)

Comment: Flirty is pretty much Iron Man's thing...

Comment: You are not allowed to edit out the content of the question if the system does not allow you to delete it.

Comment: @Null I'm receiving a bunch of gratuitous insults and downvotes for this question. If it is indeed that bad, then I should be able to delete it since, users themselves have deemed it not interesting and therefore not useful for the community.

Comment: @AlexKinman You've received both upvotes and downvotes, so not everyone thinks your question is bad. Wait a bit and you might even see it get a positive score.

Comment: @Null also, someone edited the title of the post so that it means something other than my original intention  - may question was about the Pepper/Tony relationship more so than about Tony's behavior, and somehow I'm not able to roll that back (I tried).

Comment: @AlexKinman Feel free to edit the title and/or question if you think you need to clarify something. But you can't edit it all out. Also, please use spoiler markup where appropriate.

Comment: @Null how can I delete this question. I regret it given all the negative feedback . The one person who answered also gave it negative feedback - so it's not like his answer is serious or anything.

Comment: @AlexKinman If you receive or see rude comments, feel free to flag them; moderators are here to delete inappropriate content. (I've cleaned up the comments on this question.)

Comment: I agree, I think this question is fine. People are sometimes too hostile on this site.

Comment: What I find astounding is that given the number of people who thought that the "Shoddy writing" comment was not a good one to make, not one of them actually thought to improve the question by removing it. The question is quite reasonable as it stands. There is a large shift in the stark/potts relationship off screen. I personally think the Aunt May and father figure stuff is distraction (particularly since you don't need to actually be somebody's father to be a father figure) if the focus is meant to be on the stark/potts relationship.

Comment: What is the relevance of the last spoiler tag?  What does a conversation with Peter have to do with anything in this question?

Comment: “I personally think the Aunt May and father figure stuff is distraction... if the focus is meant to be on the stark/potts relationship.” Given that Pepper appears for about sixty seconds at the end of the movie, I don’t think the focus *is* meant to be on the Stark/Potts relationship. (It is a Spider-Man movie, after all.) I think it’s just a nice, funny moment that in-universe lets us know Tony and Pepper have worked things out since *Civil War*, and out-of-universe reunites RDJ, Paltrow and Favreau who kicked off the whole MCU back in 2008.

Comment: Related question from sister site [Tony's Private life in Spider-Man: Homecoming](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/76076/tonys-private-life-in-spider-man-homecoming)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Tony Stark is a flirt (see Christine Everhart and Pepper herself in *Iron Man*, Natalie Rushman in *Iron Man 2*, and Maya Hansen in *Iron Man 3*, among others), like his father before him (see Peggy Carter in *Captain America*, and various women in *Agent Carter*).

You’re spot on about him wanting to be something of a father figure to Peter, but judging from the movie, it’s apparently at the level of wanting to maybe talk to the kid every few months and delegate most of the actual guidance to Happy Hogan, rather than wanting to start a romantic relationship with Peter’s legal guardian and become his actual step-dad.

As such, we never see any contact between Tony and May after that *Civil War* scene. In *Spider-Man: Homecoming*, he makes one reference to Aunt May’s attractiveness (in the ‘alibi video’ he makes with Peter), but immediately corrects himself as behaving inappropriately. Given his general level of flirtiness, this doesn’t seem contradictory to the later revelation that he and Pepper have worked things out post-*Civil War*.

The thread isn’t May/Tony; it’s “Aunt May is attractive”, and may have been a reference to [the fan reaction at Marisa Tomei’s casting](https://www.theguardian.com/film/2015/jul/09/marisa-tomei-spider-man-aunt-too-hot-twitter-backlash).

Comment: * [Roman**off**](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Widow)

Comment: @Gallifreyan: Romanon, Romanoff.

Comment: If you though my question was interesting enough to answer, why did you insult me in the comments section?

Comment: @AlexKinman: if you thought the film was interesting enough to ask about, why did you insult the writers in the question?

Comment: Claiming "shoddy script writing" isn't an insult. One can watch a movie and notice plot holes that tint an otherwise very good movie (as it happens I really, really liked Homecoming). You're also avoiding answering my question: If you really thought it was insulting, why did you bother answering it?

Comment: If you've seen the movie, at one point Tony actually states that he wants to treat Peter better than he was treated by his father. I forget the exact quote, but it was something along the line of "I'm trying to give you positive feedback, since my dad never gave me any...." - so, yes he does explicitly want to be a father figure to Peter.

Comment: That isn't even remotely [what a plot hole is](http://imgur.com/gallery/L7zDu).

Comment: @AlexKinman Dude. Chill. Everybody asks bad (questionable?) questions now and then. Even vets, but especially newbies like yourself. There's no need to get all huffy because you get a couple downvotes. I was going to give it a +1 until I saw your attitude. For your next question, please be prepared to take any criticism you think you don't deserve, because you're almost always going to get some no matter how hard you try.

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd: If you think the question is worth an upvote then upvote it. Refusing to upvote because you have issues with a user isn't really what the voting system is meant for.

Comment: @Chris Yeah. I know. I realized my mistake and did upvote afterwards. Sorry about that. Only wanted to explain a bit how things work around here. Will do better next time.

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd thanks for the upvote. I realize that I am coming off as pretty thin skinnked. In the Philosophy SE, where I spend most of my time, when someone downvotes a question, they are presented with message reminding them to tell user how to improve it. If the question is so far off the mark, then we simply vote to close it, as opposed to downvoting. I guess I was frustrated by how things seem to work differently here.

Comment: @AlexKinman From what I hear, every stack behaves very differently from all the rest. You get used to it after a while. :)

Comment: @AlexKinman: “he does explicitly want to be a father figure to Peter” — father *figure*, yes, in the sense of a mentor with not a great deal of time investment and apparently most of the personal contact delegated to Happy Hogan. Actual father, in the sense of starting a romantic relationship with Peter’s legal guardian: no.

Comment: @Alex: “Claiming "shoddy script writing" isn't an insult.” Then presumably claiming “shoddy film-watching” isn’t either? “If you really thought it was insulting, why did you bother answering it?” I thought the “shoddy script writing” assertion was insulting. The rest of the question seemed answerable, although given that the title I edited in didn’t reflect your meaning, I may have misunderstood it.